# My Javascript timer counter is not worked with bootstrap, please tell me how to resolve it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I am very newbie for bootstrap. Now I am doing one online exam project. So I need the time counter for that project. I am using the bootstrap for best responsive layout, and I am using this site's http://jsfiddle.net/KzrwQ/1time counter for my best result. However, unfortunately, my java script based time counter is not working properly. My problem is the countdown is not loading in that button field just "loading..." only displays no other timer is not displayed. I want this output " **loading... 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9  10 continue**". So please help to resolve it. Below I will attach my code, please refer it.it and here is my demo coding with not working result. http://jsfiddle.net/jobvirus/nFhr4/embedded/result/
Thank you!

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>online test</title> 
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" >
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-responsive.css">

</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container">
<a href="#" class="brand">responsive</a>
<div class="nav-collapse collapse pull-right">
<button type="button" id="continue" class="button red btn btn-primary">Loading...</button>
</div> 
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
<div class="hero-unit">
<h1>Here is the head line</h1>
<p>Ever</p>
<p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-large" >get start</a></p>
</div>


<script  src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="<?php echo $config['base_url']; ?>js/libs/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
 <script src="js/jquery.countTo.js"></script> <! get jquery.countTo.js from here http://jsfiddle.net/KzrwQ/1/ >
<script  src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        $('#continue').countTo({
            interval: 1000,
            startNumber: 10,
            endNumber: 0,
            onLoop: function (self, current, loop) {
                $(self).text('Wait: ' + current);
            },
            onFinish: function (self, current, loop) {
                self.removeClass('red').addClass('green');
                $(self).html('continue').on('click', function () {
                    top.location = '<?php echo('next.html'); ?>';
                });
            }
        });
    });

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Below coding is the complete version of jquery.countTo.js

```
 /**
 * countdown timer with some configuration
 *
 * @version 0.1
 * @url http://jsfiddle.net/KzrwQ/1/
 * @date 2011/09/02
 * @author Conrad 'bartrail' Barthelmes
 * @licence MIT
 *
 * usage:
 *
 * $('selector').countTo({
 *   interval:    1000,                             // miliseconds the interval is repeated (aka speed)
 *   startNumber: 10,                               // start from 10 or any other integer
 *   endNumber:   0,                                // end at 0 or any other integer
 *   
 *   onLoop:      function(self, current, loop) {   // fired on every loop
 *     self;      // the fetched element
 *     current;   // current number of interval
 *     loop;      // finished loops
 *
 *     // default behaviour:
 *     $(self).text(current);
 *   },
 *   
 *   onStart:     function(self) {                  // fired on the beginning
 *     self;      // the fetched element
 *   },
 *
 *   onFinish:    function(self, current, loop) {   // fired when finished
 *     self;      // the fetched element
 *     current;   // current number of interval
 *     loop;      // finished loops
 *   }
 * });
 * 
 */
jQuery.fn.countTo = function(options) {
  if(this.length == 0) {
    return;
  }
  // save reference to self
  var self     = this;
  // merge optoins
  self.options = {};
  jQuery.extend(true, self.options, {
    interval   : 1000,
    startNumber: 10,
    endNumber  : 0,
    onLoop     : function(self, current, loop) {
      $(self).text(current);
    },
    onStart    : function(self) {},
    onFinish   : function(self, current, loop) {}
  }, options);

  // init the start number
  self.current   = self.options.startNumber;
  // get the direction, true is 'down', false is 'up'
  self.direction = self.options.startNumber > self.options.endNumber ? true : false;
  // the current iteration
  self.loop      = 0;
  // whether is finished or not
  self.finished  = false;
  // the timing function
  self.timer     = function(self) {
    self.intervalId = setInterval(self._interval, self.options.interval)
  }

  self._interval  = function() {
    self.options.onLoop(self, self.current, self.loop);
    // going down
    if(self.direction) {
      if(self.current > self.options.endNumber) {
        self.current--;
      }else{
        self.finished = true;
      }
    // going up
    }else{
      if(self.current < self.options.endNumber) {
        self.current++;
      }else{
        self.finished = true;
      }
    }
    // clear interval and fire onFinish when finished
    if(self.finished) {
      clearInterval(self.intervalId);
      self.options.onFinish(self, self.current, self.loop)
    }
    self.loop++;
  }

  self.start = function(self) {
    self.options.onStart(self);
    self.timer(self);
  }

  self.start(self);
}
```

Comment: Describe the problem and provide a jsfiddle of your code. You can't just post your code and expect help. That's why nobody commented or answered.

Comment: @alkis: Just now only I edited my question and added what is my exact problem? And jsfiddle page with my not working coding, please help to find the solution.

Comment: @alkis: Your coding is now working dude thanks a lot, and few hours back I am editing some contents and add some coding, but it is automatically hiding. After that I clicked edit button. Its shows my newly content part in red line, sorry friend, I am very newbie to stackoverflow just now only I found this error so now I am changed my content. I think it will fulfill your requirements.

Comment: They are not my requirements (just to be clear). I was not trying to be an ass, just trying to help you. Your problem was not difficult, but your didn't have any response because of a bad question. If you did all those things from the start, you would have had an answer in minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think now it works.

http://jsfiddle.net/pXq9f/

But you still didn't explain what the problem was, so I'm guessing this is the expected behavior.

```
jQuery.fn.countTo = function (options) {
    if (this.length == 0) {
        return;
    }
    // save reference to self
    var self = this;
    // merge optoins
    self.options = {};
    jQuery.extend(true, self.options, {
        interval: 1000,
        startNumber: 10,
        endNumber: 0,
        onLoop: function (self, current, loop) {
            $(self).text(current);
        },
        onStart: function (self) {},
        onFinish: function (self, current, loop) {}
    }, options);

    // init the start number
    self.current = self.options.startNumber;
    // get the direction, true is 'down', false is 'up'
    self.direction = self.options.startNumber > self.options.endNumber ? true : false;
    // the current iteration
    self.loop = 0;
    // whether is finished or not
    self.finished = false;
    // the timing function
    self.timer = function (self) {
        self.intervalId = setInterval(self._interval, self.options.interval)
    }

    self._interval = function () {
        self.options.onLoop(self, self.current, self.loop);
        // going down
        if (self.direction) {
            if (self.current > self.options.endNumber) {
                self.current--;
            } else {
                self.finished = true;
            }
            // going up
        } else {
            if (self.current < self.options.endNumber) {
                self.current++;
            } else {
                self.finished = true;
            }
        }
        // clear interval and fire onFinish when finished
        if (self.finished) {
            clearInterval(self.intervalId);
            self.options.onFinish(self, self.current, self.loop)
        }
        self.loop++;
    }

    self.start = function (self) {
        self.options.onStart(self);
        self.timer(self);
    }

    self.start(self);
}



 $('#continue').countTo({
            interval: 1000,
            startNumber: 10,
            endNumber: 0,
            onLoop: function(self, current, loop) {
                $(self).text('Wait: ' + current);
            },
            onFinish: function(self, current, loop) {
                self.removeClass('red').addClass('green');
                $(self).html('continue').on('click', function() {
                    top.location = next.html;
                });
            }
        });
```

Comment: After the count down timer ending I clicked the continue button nothing will happen. I want if I am click the continue buttoun it will goto next.html page.your time counter is working well friend but please correct some little errors for me. Thank you!

Comment: Now I am correcting your small error friend in your .js coding. I changed index.html into 'index.html' that's all. Now it works perfectly. Thanks for your awesome coding dude!

Comment: Yeah I tried to fix the counter and didn't check the other stuff. Anyway glad it worked